# Convert NSString with other NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I've 3 `NSString` and 1 NSArray with value, i try to convert all strings in one:

```
string01 = [string01 stringByAppendingString:[numbersValue objectAtIndex:Value1 -1]];
string03 = [string02 stringByAppendingString:[numbersValue objectAtIndex:Value2 -1]];
string03 = [string03 stringByAppendingString:[numbersValue objectAtIndex:Value3 -1]];

//here i will to convert value of striing01 in to string02 and string02 in to string03 than take last string in my UITextView

resulteString = [resulteString stringByAppendingString:<what i can write here?>];

[myTextView setText:resulteString];
```

Is Like a Enigma Machine, for example if you think a keyboard and press A,

```
A pass inside a string01 and become B,
B pass inside a string02 and become C,
C pass inside string03 and become D
in my text view i need to see only D
```

Comment: Do you only want concatenate string01, string02 and string03? `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", string01, string02, string03]`

Comment: Please add an example.

Comment: This is not ENIGMA, but ROT-3

Comment: This is not ENIGMA, but a Caesar cipher. I have a Captain Midnight decoder that will do this. ;-) @vikingosegundo ROT-3 if the code wasn't so flawed but it seems that the OP is trying to obtain RORT-3.

Comment: The second line of your code is wrong. You're assigning to string03 instead of string02.

Answer (score 1):

if resulteString is an object of NSString class
then use

```
resultString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@", resultString,string01, string02, string03];
```

else if resulteString is an object of NSMutableString class

```
   resulteString = [resulteString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@%@%@", string01, string02, string03];
```

may help you.

Comment: Thks, i know that, but i need only one result, for example if you think a keyboard and press A, A pass inside a string01 and become B, B pass inside a string02 and become C, and C pass inside string03 and become D in my text view i need to see only D

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you mean. If you want to encrypt your string by shifting you need a method like this:

```
//Edit this method how you want to use this is just an example
-(NSString *) encodeString:(NSString *) realString{
    NSArray *alphabet=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"A",@"B",@"C",@"D",@"E",@"F",@"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"R",@"S",@"T",@"U",@"V",@"W",@"Y",@"Z",nil];
    int index=[alphabet indexOfObject:realString];
    index ++;
    NSString *resultString=[alphabet objectAtIndex:index];
    return resultString;

}
```

you need to this character by character. Use UITextField's delegate
everytime you click on keyboard, call this method and you are gonna get new string. And append this string to another everytime.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
[NSArray componentsJoinedByString]
```

Comment: please see my description adding now

Comment: Seen and appendString functions seems reasonable but what's wrong with it?

Comment: I've to change a single value, with this method i have all result in same time

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
First write
in YourController.h file NSString *newString;

// Add below line in viewDidLoad
newString = @""; 
// In Your function
// A pressed from keyboard
NSString *str1 = @"Newly pressed Keyboard Key";  
// Add New Pressed key with existing one
newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",newString,str1];
```

This way you can add this in one function and call when user pressed any key from keyboard.

Hope this will help you.